# Efficently Parse out Key-Value Data

Tags: powershell, key-value

Dataset:

```
Key         Value
Item#1      1
Item#1      2
Item#1      3
Item#2      4
Item#2      2
Item#2      3
Item#3      1
Item#3      2
Item#3      3
```

Ultimatly, the end goal is pull the first value for every unique key.  So for example from the data set above, I would want to pull Value 1, 4, and 1 because it is the first entry for each key.

I have this code, put it pulls the unique key name, not the value.  I am probably missing something simple, so any help is appreciated

```
$CollectionTable.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Key -Like 'Item#' } | Select-Object { $_.key } -Unique
```

Under the Select-Object, I have attempted to do $_.Value, but that returns every unique Value where the Item starts with "Item#"

Comment: How is your data being stored in `$CollectionTable`?  It seems as if you're treating it as a hashtable, but then you'd have duplicate keys, which won't work.

Comment: `$CollectionTable |Group-Object Key |ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0].Value }`

Comment: $CollectionTable is where the dataset is being stored.  It is a Systems.Collection.Generic.KeyVaulePair Object that is created when running a command from a dll object,

Comment: In case of a collection of `KeyValuePair`s: `$CollectionTable.Keys |Get-Unique |ForEach-Object { $CollectionTable.$_[0] }`

Comment: $CollectionTable.Keys |Get-Unique |ForEach-Object { $CollectionTable.$_[0] } returns everything as null, but the first comment you made got me farther than i was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was an object table like:

```
$CollectionTable = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Key,         Value
Item#1,      1
Item#1,      2
Item#1,      3
Item#2,      4
Item#2,      2
Item#2,      3
Item#3,      1
Item#3,      2
Item#3,      3
'@
```

It would be:

```
$CollectionTable |Group-Object Key |ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0].Value }
1
4
1
```

As it appears to be a table of [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2) Structures:

```
$CollectionTable = $CollectionTable |ForEach-Object {
    [Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[String,Int]]::New($_.Key, $_.Value)
}
```

It would be:

```
$CollectionTable.Key |Get-Unique |ForEach-Object {
    ($CollectionTable |Where-Object Key -eq $_)[0].Value
}
1
4
1
```

You might also use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) for this:

```
$Keys = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::New()
$CollectionTable.Where{ $Keys.Add($_.Key) }.Value
1
4
1
```