# Where object as variable

Tags: powershell, where-clause

After reading many of the posted solutions here, none fully applies mine.
This works (returns expected number of instancesNames based on criteria):

```
$response.result | Where-Object {$_.targetType -eq "webserver" -and ($_.agentHostName -eq "ServerA" -or $_.agentHostName -eq "ServerB")} | select-Object "instanceName"
```

However, since n number of servers may be found, I created a loop to dynamically create this query:

```
    [System.Text.StringBuilder]$clause = " {`$_.targetType -eq ""webserver"" -and (" 
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($server in $serversArray) {
    
        if ( $i -eq $serversArray.Count ) {
            $clause.Append("`$_.agentHostName -eq ""${server}"")}")
        } else {
            $clause.Append( "`$_.agentHostName -eq ""${server}"" -or ")
        }   
        $i++
    }
    $clause.Append(" | select-Object ""instanceName""")

$filter = [scriptblock]::Create($clause)
$instances = $response.result | where-object $filter
```

debugging:
the $clause variable contains:

```
{$_.targetType -eq "webserver" -and ($_.agentHostName -eq "serverA" -or $_.agentHostName -eq "serverB")} | select-Object "instanceName"
```

However, it returns all instanceNames (not filtered) instead of the ones that meet the criteria. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not use the `-in` operator?  For example: `$response.result | Where-Object {($_.targetType -eq "webserver") -and ($_.agentHostName -in $serversArray)} | select-Object "instanceName"`.

Comment: This is a very odd and expensive way of getting unique servers. For what you are trying, you probably just need to supply the filter: `$filter = [scriptblock]::Create('$_.targetType -eq "webserver" -and ($_.agentHostName -eq "serverA" -or $_.agentHostName -eq "serverB")')` and not the `Select-Object`. Anyways there are other fast ways to select just unique item, e.g. using a hashset: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69135364/1701026

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-in-and--notin) operator would simplify your code.  For example:

```
$response.result | 
    Where-Object {($_.targetType -eq 'webserver') -and ($_.agentHostName -in $serversArray)} |
    Select-Object 'instanceName'
```