# How to user where-object with a variable input

Tags: powershell, variables, where-object

Ok so I am trying to use a variable to make up a where statement on a get-aduser command.

This is what I am trying to emulate which works:

```
get-aduser -filter * | where { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Users,DC*" }
```

- Note the are asterix before and after the User,DC.  Not showing for some reason.

So here is what I have in the script which returns nothing:

```
$SearchBase = (get-addomain).DistinguishedName
$DefaultUsersOU = "*OU=Users," + $SearchBase

get-aduser -Filter * -Properties lastLogonTimeStamp -Searchbase "$($SearchBase)" | where-object { $_.DistinguishedName -like $DefaultUsersOU }
```

Found a similar article on here [Where object as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897339/where-object-as-variable) but if I apply that thinking to the DistinguishedName field it doesnt work either.

Comment: You can just search at the OU level of Users. Remove the asterisk in `$DefaultUsersOu` and leave the concatenating of the 2 strings. Then you wouldn't need a `Where` filter to search for user accounts in that OU. `Get-ADUser ... -SearchBase 'OU=Users,DC=..,DC=..'`

Comment: You can use contains instead of asterisk : $_.DistinguishedName.Cojntains("Users,DC")